# image cannot be displayed, becuase it contains errors - BLOB

Tags: php, blob

Can anyone see whats wrong with this code?

```
$max = 10000000; 
foreach ($_FILES["file"]["error"] as $file => $error) {     
    if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        if($_FILES['file']['size'][$file] < $max) {   
               $img= file_get_contents($_FILES['evidence']['tmp_name'][$evidence]);
                $img= mysql_real_escape_string($img);
                $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'][$file];
                $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'][$file];
                $sql = "INSERT INTO attached_evidence (id, image, size, type, date) 
                VALUES  ('$id', '$img', '$fileSize', '$fileType', NOW());";
                mysql_query($sql) or die("Error in Query: " . mysql_error());
        }
        else{
            echo 'Too big';
        }
    }
}
```

As I output my blob on another page using...

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM test_image";
    $result = @mysql_query($query)  or die ("query failed: " . mysql_error());   
    if($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){          
  header('Content-type: image/'.$row['type'].'');
$blob_data = $row['image'];
    echo $blob_data;
        
            }
    else {
            

echo "No images were found";
        }
```

The ..... image cannot be displayed, becuase it contains errors.

Any ideas?

Thanks

EDITTED

Comment: why are you adding slashes to the image data? you don't need to. It's binary data, not a string.

Comment: Nopes. Not for binary data such as that.

Comment: if I removed it, would it still work or do i need to add other things in?

Comment: Try it :-) Make sure there is absolutely no white space before outputting the image data.

Comment: ive editted it all and no spaces...still giving me the same error

Answer (score 1):

```
   VALUES  ('$id', '$imgData', 'fileSize', 'fileType', NOW());";
```

Your file type is always "fileType" and your size always "fileSize" (does that even store correctly in the database?). So your image type on output is always `image/fileType`, which is at least one of your problems.

You also seem to be attempting to use `finfo` there, but in the end are just using the user-supplied MIME type from the `$_FILES` array, which you should never ever do.

You're also not escaping the values before putting them into the SQL query. `addslashes` is not the same as `mysql_real_escape_string` or prepared statements.

You should also get used to *failing early* instead of endless nested `if`s:

```
if ($error !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    echo 'fail';
    continue;
}

if ($_FILES['file']['size'][$file] > $max) {
    echo 'fail';
    continue;
}

...
```

Comment: sorry was meant to be $fileSize and $fileType but that isnt the error

Comment: @user Then we could go on guessing for a long time here. Check the image data after upload, how it's stored in the database and then again on output to find any discrepancies. I'd recommend `bin2hex($blob)` and a diff tool for that.

Comment: @user Try to incorporate my feedback into your existing code.

Comment: it is sorted as .... FFD8FFE000104A46494600010101004800480000FFDB0043000503040404030504040405050506070C08070707070F0B0B090C110F1212110F11111316 and it goes on....

Comment: or even better, do an md5 hash of the file before you upload it. And then do an MD5 hash of the blob you have stored in the db. Much easier. if they match, it's all good, if not, then something is up....

Comment: @Flukey As a first step, sure, but I'd be interested in how exactly it screws up if it screws up... :)

Comment: Comparing hex values isn't going to help him to know how it screwed up. If the hash value of the blob matches the hash value of the file then that's fine, he can then move on to the real problem: why it's not displaying correctly. Any whitespace perhaps? wrong header type? leading comma? etc. etc. :-)

Comment: is that the whole script you've posted? No html anywhere?

Comment: no, im currently working on a new page and once ive got this working, i would add this into my current code..

Comment: the page where you're outputting the image, have you posted all of the code for that?

Comment: Like i've said, make sure you have no whitespace **anywhere**